# Всем привет помоги с Админ панелем

Tags: html, mysql, node.js, android-studio

## Подскажите как подключить созданный АдминПанель к NodeJs.

Все пересмотрел все создают на .ejs. Когда я так создавал он не подключался к Android Studio. Пожалуйста помогите просто все кипит до невозможного. Некоторые советовали создать Сервер по отдельности. Это-отдельно для АдминПанели и отдельно для Android studio.